# Sorting First Array With The Order Of Second Array

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

Suppose I am having two arrays namely **namesArray** and **names** as below

```
var namesArray = [{"name":"Charlie","age":3},{"name":"Dog","age":1},{"name":"Baker","age":7},{"name":"Abel","age":9}];

var names = ['Baker', 'Dog', 'Abel', 'Charlie'];
```

Can I achieve the following in **UnderscoreJS**  so that sort the array named **namesArray** in a order so that all the name elements of **namesArray** will be in the same order of **names** .

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can we see some code that indicates, you've at least given it a try?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Underscore but simple coding skills and plain javascript

Answer (score 2):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with an object as reference for the sort order.

```js
var namesArray = [{ "name": "Charlie", "age": 3 }, { "name": "Dog", "age": 1 }, { "name": "Baker", "age": 7 }, { "name": "Abel", "age": 9 }],
    names = ['Baker', 'Dog', 'Abel', 'Charlie'],
    hash = Object.create(null);

names.forEach(function (a, i) {
    hash[a] = i + 1;
});

namesArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (hash[a.name] || 0) - (hash[b.name] || 0);
});

console.log(namesArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the index of each name in `sort()`. Not as performant as creating hash of indexes but chances are it's not that critical either

```
namesArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return names.indexOf(a.name) - names.indexOf(b.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not lot to do with underscrore but you can do it like this:
I think using hash like [what Nina does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38178794/3078890) would be better than indexOf with respect to performance.

```js
var namesArray = [{ "name": "Charlie", "age": 3 }, { "name": "Dog", "age": 1 }, { "name": "Baker", "age": 7 }, { "name": "Abel", "age": 9 }];

var names = ['Baker', 'Dog', 'Abel', 'Charlie'];
var sorted = _.sortBy(namesArray, o => names.indexOf(o.name));

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```